# Форма Авторизации C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

Есть некая форма в которой произошла авторизация - переход на другую форму. Выглядит это так:

```
String login = Edit1->Text;
    String psw = Edit2->Text;

    ADOQuery1->SQL->Clear();
    ADOQuery1->SQL->Text = "SELECT * FROM users where login = '" + login + "' and psw = '" + psw + "' ";
    ADOQuery1->Open();


    if(ADOQuery1->RecordCount > 0){
        Form1->Hide();
        Form2->Show();
        Edit1->Clear();
        Edit2->Clear();
    }
```

Когда перешел на новую форму, мне к примеру надо вывести ник user-а в Form2. При разработке сайтов я использовал сессию. То есть создавал сессию и передавал в нее значение "ник юзера". После чего выводил на сайте.
Как реализовать тоже самое здесь?

Answer (score 0):

если ник юзера это 'login' то просто пишете перед вызовом формы Form2->Show() схематично:

Form2-><имя public переменной или компонента>->Text = login;

а в событии OnShow() формы Form2 делаете с этим значением то что нужно - переносите туда где он будет отображаться (в TEdit или куда еще - Вам виднее).